# Gnome Online Accounts: Unacceptable TLS certificate

Tags: gnome

When I try to login with my Colorado School District 11 Google account, I get a white screen with only this message: `Unacceptable TLS certificate`.

They have a browser SSO page that should be pulled up and does with most other things, and I verified via Google Chrome that the D11 SSO page has a valid SSL certificate.

Does that mean gnome-online-accounts is only supposed to accept Google's password page? If so, please add something to allow me (and other students) to log in. If the gnome-online-accounts menu only supports TLS certificates (and not SSL), please make an option to go ahead with the connection anyway. (Or browser login option for either)

I'm not running proxy or a vpn or anything of the sort. I'm currently running Focal Fossa, but had this problem when I was running bionic and eoan.

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Answer (score 1):

Attempts to manually add the flathub repository, reinstall flatpak, GNOME, and curl were unsuccessful and resulted in the error `Unacceptable TLS certificate`.

My solution was very easy.  All I had to do was reinstall the CA certificate with the following command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall  ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, SSO for New York University, and running Focal Fossa, the required libraries weren't installed. This is how I was able to rectify it.

Install Synaptic Package Manager from Ubuntu Software Library.
Install the following libraries (assuming your organization also follows/uses the same protocols):- apache2, SAML/SAML2, SSO and OAuth.

If Shibboleth protocol is used, try installing it, but there would be dependency issues, since Ubuntu 20.04 is not yet supported. In my case it worked without installing it.

A word of CAUTION, there would be multiple versions of these libraries, based on different languages, install the appropriate ones or if you are not sure and you have a generous disk space, install all variants.

Comment: What are the specific names of the packages you installed? (Like `liboauth0` or `libsaml10` ?)

Comment: Almost all libraries would start with 'lib', so you have to look for that. As far as the version goes, I am not proud of it, but I did not know what version my university was using, so I installed all of it. If you can, contact your organization's IT department and find out what versions are they using or you can install everything (which though I did, is not an ideal solution).